# Showing the density of primes around $n$ is approximately $1/\ln(n)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The following shows the density of primes around $x$ is approximately $1/\ln(x)$. The argument, although based on approximation, benefits from being simple enough for those without advanced mathematics to understand.

**Question** - is the argument valid? Are there errors in the logic?

---

**Step 1**

We start by examining the prime factors of $n!$.

Multiples of prime $p$ contribute $\lfloor n/p \rfloor$ factors, multiples of $p^2$ contribute $\lfloor n/p^2 \rfloor$, and so on.

Therefore the number of prime factors $p$ of $n!$, written $\nu_p(n!)$ is:

$$\nu_{p}(n!)=\sum_{k}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{k}}\right\rfloor $$

Like any integer, $n!$ is a product of all its prime factors:

$$ n! = \prod_{p\leq n} p^{\nu_p(n!)}$$

We can take the logarithm to turn the product into a sum:

$$ \sum_{k \leq n} \ln(k) = \sum_{p \leq n} \nu_p(n!) \ln(p)$$

We'll example the LHS and RHS of this expression.

---

**Step 2**

We can approximate the LHS sum with an integral.

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{k \leq n} \ln(k) &\approx \int_2^n ln(x)\;dx \\ \\ &\approx n\left(\ln(n)-1\right) -2\left(\ln2-1\right) \\ \\ &\approx n\left(\ln(n)-1\right)  \end{align}$$

We've discarded the constant $2(\ln2-1)$ as it is small compared to large $n$. Similarly, the upper limit of the integral is $n$ and not $n+1$ because for large $n$, $\ln(n+1)\approx\ln(n)$.

---

**Step 3**

The RHS can be simplified if we can find an easier approximation for $\nu_p(n!)$. We do this by considering lower and upper bounds for it.

Let's compare $\nu_p(n!)$ to the first expression in its expansion.

$$ \nu_{p}(n!)\geq\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor >\frac{n}{p}-1 $$

Let's now consider the expansion of $\nu_p(n!)$ but with each term without the floor operator $\lfloor \rfloor$ applied.

$$ \nu_{p}(n!)\leq\sum_{k}\frac{n}{p^{k}}=\frac{n}{p}\frac{1}{1-1/p}=\frac{n}{p-1} $$

We can combine these lower and upper bounds.

$$ \frac{n}{p}-1 < \nu_p(n!) \leq \frac{n}{p-1} $$

For large $n$, we can approximate

$$\nu_p(n!) \approx n/p$$

---

**Step 4**

Let's remind ourselves of the key equality before we apply these approximations.

$$ \sum_{k \leq n} \ln(k) = \sum_{p \leq n} \nu_p(n!) \ln(p)$$

Replacing the LHS and RHS with our approximations.

$$ \begin{align} n\left(\ln(n)-1\right) &\approx \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{n}{p} \ln(p) \\ \\  \ln(n)-1 & \approx \sum_{p \leq n} \frac{\ln(p)}{p}\end{align} $$

If we now think about the rate of change of both sides with respect to $n$, that is, the derivative $d/dn$.

$$ \frac{1}{n} \approx \rho(n) \frac{\ln(n)}{n} $$

Here $\rho(n)$ is the the density of primes around $n$. The rationale for it is that the sum increases when $n$ is a prime, and this happens at a rate of $\rho(n)$ by definition of $\rho(n)$.

Rearranging gives us our desired result.

$$ \boxed{ \rho(n) \approx \frac{1}{\ln(n)} } $$

---

The approach here is inspired by this YouTube video [[link]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVaSA_b938U).

Comment: To make this mean anything, you need to get some sense of the error of everything where you've written $\approx.$ But it is a good start as a motivation for the result.

Comment: the other problem is that $ \approx $ may or may not behave well wr differentiation as it is easy to construct example for which $f(n)  \approx  g(n)$ but $f(n)-g(n)$ oscillates so much that the derivative of the oscillation swamps $f'(n)$ so $f'(n)$ is far from $g'(n)$

Comment: My biggest question is the $\nu_p(n)\approx n/p.$ Most of your other estimates can be written as $\sim$ as $n\to\infty,$ an asymptotic relationship, but you don't get an asymptote for $\nu_p(n)$ except for fixed $p.$

Comment: What is "$\rho(n)$ the density of primes around $n$" it seems that you forgot to check what it would mean

Comment: Is it worth me pursing this line of argument? Do more knowledgeable people here know that (1) we can't show that $\approx$ behaves well under differentiation as per Conrad's point, and (2) whether $\nu_p(n)\approx n/p$ can't be shown to behave well either? If it is worth pursuing - I would welcome pointers/suggestions as to lines of attack.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - could $\nu_p(n!) \approx n/p$ be argued as "for large n, and most p" the approximation holds, whilst acknowledging that for "p close to n" it doesn't, but p close to n is statistically rarer?

Comment: @Penelope You might wish to have a look at the big O-notation to make your approximation process more rigorous.

Comment: hi @Conrad - having had a think during a walk... can we say the function we're trying to differentiate is monotonically increasing and therefore avoids the oscillation issue?

Comment: the point is about the difference included in $\approx$ - we know that PNT is true so the difference behaves; as a heuristic, the above is ok-ish though the subtle points can go wrong (again we know that PNT is true so they do not but they may), but then Chebushev estimates using the binomial coefficients are elementary and show easily that if the density exists in a meaningful way, it must ne $1/\ln n$, so ultimately not sure what is the point of this argument; the hard non-elementary part has been understood for almost 200 years to be showing that the density exists, not that it is $1/\ln n$

Comment: hi @Conrad - my aim is to show the density is $1/\ln(n)$ using a method maximally accessible to non-experts. I will investigate the Chebyshev approach using the binomial coefficients to see if that arrives at the desired conclusion in a manner fraught with fewer dangers.

Comment: again not sure exactly what you mean by "show the density is $1/\ln n$" as that has two parts, namely show that the density exists (hard even today with simplest approaches still requiring a fair bit of complex analysis, while those without complex analysis quite tortuous) and then if it exists it is $1/\ln n$ (easy and known for almost 200 years)

Comment: @Conrad I spent a couple of hours trying to find resources on the Chebyshev approach to showing that if the density exists, it must be inverse logarithmic. I'd appreciate a pointer. I need more time to understand the "existence" point and how to tackle it for a non-expert audience.

Comment: a very concise but easy to understand place to look is in Iwaniec and Kowalski Analytic Number Theory p 33 where they show that with the usual definition of $\psi(x)=\sum_{p^n \le x}\log p$ that $\sum_{k \ge 1} (-1)^{k+1}\psi(x/k)=x\log 2+O(\log x)$ which immediately implies that if $\psi(x)/x \to l$ then $l=1$ as well as implying that $c_1x \le \psi(x) \le c_2x$; summation by parts easily relates $\psi$ with $\pi(x)$ so giving the related results

Comment: Something Chebyshev did show is that $x/\log x$ is the correct "order of magnitude" of $\pi(x)$, in the sense that the ratio $\pi(x)/(x/\log x)$ is bounded above and below by positive constants.  However, this is *very* far from any kind of serious argument about estimating the decay of $\pi(x)/x$ to behave asymptotically like $1/\log x$.  Why the interest in trying to present such an argument to a non-expert audience? For most people outside of math, their eyes are likely to glaze over as soon as logarithms appear.

Comment: hi @KCd - why the interest in reaching a non-expert audience? because I believe there are many many people like me who wished such accessible resources had existed ... currently almost all the content out there has a high barrier to entry and means many people who could appreciate the beauty and excitement of mathematics never get to appreciate it.

Comment: @Penelope  I understand what you mean, but I think people far-removed from math can appreciate the apparent smoothing of the step function of prime counts as you zoom out but most are not likely to be interested in seeing careful derivations of  formulas that quantify the relation. (For someone just learning about logarithms, however, the situation could be different.) Barry Mazur and William Stein wrote a book on *Prime numbers and the Riemann Hypothesis* aimed at a general audience: see how they explain the statistical behavior of primes using many pictures, if I am recalling it correctly.

Comment: hi @KCd - in my opinion (and I'm no expert). the Mazur book fails as it starts easy but then makes huge leaps with lots unexplained. I found the Derbyshire book much better in terms of a less jumpy journey for general readers. I guess there is always opportunity if you feel existing content has a gap ...

Answer (score 1):

Having watched the same video recently, I was wondering about the exact same thing, which led me to this post (painful that it’s almost two years late). The argument is an intuitive and accessible way to understand the distribution of primes. Let’s try applying the same logic to the distributions of other numbers, to see if the argument holds.

For this, let's consider the distribution of the perfect squares. First let's identify the probability that a randomly selected number around N is a perfect square. Useful to this process will be understanding the fact that the number of perfect squares less than N is exactly equal to the floor, of the square root of N (the square of every integer less than $\sqrt{N}$ must be less than N, therefore the floor of the square root of N will handily give us a count of all the perfect squares less than N), yet for our purposes an approximation will suffice:
$$\sqrt{N}\approx \lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor\tag{1}$$
Let's now derive an explicit formula for the probability of selecting a perfect square out of the interval of values within 25% of N. The choice of 25% here is arbitrary, and just for illustrative purposes (the reason for this will be explained). This would be given by the number of perfect squares less than 1.25N minus the number of perfect squares less than 0.75N, divided by the length of the interval, all of which we have the ability to compute. Therefore we have:
$$\delta(N) = \frac{\sqrt{1.25N}-\sqrt{0.75N}}{1.25N-0.75N}\tag{2}$$
Where $\delta(N)$ is the probability that numbers near N are perfect squares. This reduces easily to:
$$\delta(N) = \frac{\sqrt{1.25}-\sqrt{0.75}}{0.5}*\frac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\tag{3}$$
Thus it suffices to say that the constant out front in this expression clearly depends on the length of the interval, therefore in general we have:
$$\delta(N)\ \alpha\ \frac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\tag{4}$$
Note that in integrating this expression from $0$ to x we should obtain an expression for the number of perfect squares less than x, which should agree with what we previously established, and indeed:
$$\int_0^x\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}dn\ \alpha \ \sqrt{x}\tag{5}$$
Which is approximately equal to the floor of the square root, which is precisely equal to the number of perfect squares less than x. Excellent! So we have established that this method of integrating a function which we find to give us the relative density of a certain type of number should give us the amount of those numbers less than the upper bound of the integral.

The key difference here is that we were able to precisely capture the probability of numbers near an input being perfect squares, which with prime numbers, at least to my knowledge, is impossible.

So let's imagine a situation wherein the exact probability of numbers near an input being perfect squares was unknown, and let's try to apply an argument similar to the one seen in the Zetamath video/your question to see if the reasoning is solid.

Now this will prove to be much easier, seeing as how we won't be forced to approximate a third party via calculus and discrete mathematics (such as in the case of the primes), and instead we can just approximate the sum directly. So to start we derive an equation for the sum of the perfect squares less than an input, N. This is quite simple, seeing as how it is just the sum of the squares of the integers less than the square root of N:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}i^2\approx\sum_{i=0}^{\sqrt{n}}i^2\tag{6}$$
Now we can approximate this sum using the [widely known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) for the sum of the first n squares, which is only an approximation because it extends the sum to all real numbers making it a continuous rather than a discrete function (Note: here we are summing the squares of all the integers less than the square root of N, not N itself, so we have to plug in the square root of n to our formula).
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\sqrt{n}}i^2\approx\frac13n^{\frac32}+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{6}\tag{7}$$
Now here, we can attempt to differentiate both sides. Differentiating the right is trivial, and in an argument similar to the OP, the left will yield some probability function that the numbers near the input value, n, are perfect squares, multiplied by the amount the sum would increase by if a small increase in n encompassed a perfect square, which of course, would be equal to the value of that perfect square, n. Proceeding as such, we have:
$$\delta(n)n\approx\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}+\frac12+\frac{1}{12\sqrt{n}}\tag{8}$$
Isolating $\delta(n)$, which should give us an expression for the probability of numbers near n being perfect squares, we have:
$$\delta(n)\approx\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{12}n^{-3/2}\tag{9}$$
Now this is only an approximation, but notice that as our input for n gets larger and larger, the behavior of the second and third terms of this expression both tend towards zero. Since we are approximating here, I will just declare that therefore, this probability function is approximately just equal to the first term, $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$. As such, we have
$$\delta(n)\approx\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\tag{10}$$
Integrating this expression from $0$ to x, we should expect to approximate the number of perfect squares less than x, and indeed, in carrying out that integration we have:
$$\int_0^x\delta(n)dx=\sqrt{x}\approx\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor\tag{11}$$
I also want to point out that if you carry out the same process without omitting the second and third terms of our original approximation in eq. $9$ (integrating from $1$ to avoid division by zero), you will still have a relatively accurate *approximation* for the number of perfect squares less than x. It won't be as good, but it is actually a much better approximation than the logarithmic integral is for the prime counting function. That is to say:
$$\int_1^x\delta(n)dx\approx\int_1^x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{12}n^{-3/2}dx\approx\sqrt{x}+ln(\sqrt{x})-\frac{1}{6\sqrt{x}}\approx\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor\tag{12}$$
Which is largely due to how incredibly slowly the logarithm of the square root grows relative to the square root of x.

The cool thing about this exercise is that we have the benefit of knowing exactly how the perfect squares are distributed, so in this instance we can actually precisely identify the error of this estimation, which incidentally works out to be:
$$(\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor-\sqrt{x})+ln(\sqrt{x})-\frac{1}{6\sqrt{x}}\tag{13}$$
So to demonstrate that this approximation is indeed significantly better than the logarithmic integral is for the prime counting function, I played around with the error in desmos and was pleasantly surprised to find that the error of this approximation, at least empirically appears to grows slower than even the 100th root of x.
[If you're curious look at the data here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMzWB.png) This is an interesting analog to the Riemann Hypothesis, which to me is enlightening seeing as how we have precise intel into the nature of the error.